# Problem with table name in Laravel Eloquent many to many relathionship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I am implementing a many to many relationship between 'suppliers' and 'brands' table. my Models are Supplier, Brand, BrandSupplier. my tables are suppliers, brands, brand_suppliers. I know that Laravel by default search for pivot table with brand_supplier, but my migration created it as brand_suppliers. how can I override the table name.

Supplier model:

```
public function brands(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class)->using(BrandSupplier::class);
    }
```

Brand model:

```
public function suppliers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class)->using(BrandSupplier::class);
    }
```

BrandSupplier model:

```
class BrandSupplier extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'brand_suppliers';
}
```

I tired with this above one. but, its not working.

Comment: What do you mean by *"... but, it's not working."*

Comment: It should be `brand_supplier`

Answer (score 1):

The [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships) are incredibly good for things like this and the laravel framework is very consistent, so often trying out what 'should' work willl get you the solution.

You should be able to do this.

```
function brands(){
   $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class, 'brand_suppliers');

}
```